# Sign in option creation using jsp and oracle database

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to create a social network and hence a sign in option. The basic working is: Collect email id and password and check if they are right -> if RIGHT, direct to welcome.jsp page/ if WRONG, inform the user about that. I am using oracle database connection.

Here is the code for the login.jsp part:

```
    <script>

        var xmlhttp;
        var s;

        function checkDetails()
        {
            emailIn = document.getElementById("email").value;
            pwIn = document.getElementById("pw").value;
            alert(emailIn+"  "+pwIn);
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = showMessage;
            xmlhttp.open("GET","matchDetails.jsp?EMAIL="+emailIn+"&PW="+pwIn, true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }

        function showMessage()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
                alert(xmlhttp.status);
                var ans = xmlhttp.responseText;
                alert("1."+ans);
                if (ans == "WrongPw") 
                {
                    alert("2."+ans);
                    document.getElementById("emailCheck").innerHTML = "Incorrect password. Please try again";
                    document.getElementById("pw").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("pw").focus();
                }
                else if (ans == "WrongEmail")
                {
                    alert("3."+ans);
                    document.getElementById("pwCheck").innerHTML = "The entered user id does not exist";
                    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("pw").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("email").focus();
                }
                else if (ans == "BothWrong")
                {
                    document.getElementById("emailCheck").innerHTML = "The entered user id does not exist";
                    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("pw").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("email").focus();
                }
                else if (ans == "BothMatch")
                {
                    alert("final: "+ans);
                    window.location.href("welcome.jsp");
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Furhter, the html part that calls the function is as follows:

```
    <form method="POST" name="frm1">                
        Email id:</br>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></br></br>
        <div id="emailCheck" value="">
        Password:</br>
        <input type="password" id="pw" name="pw" onblur="checkDetails()"></br></br>       
        <div id="pwCheck" value="">
    </form>
```

And next the matchDetails.jsp code is here:

```
    <%
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        java.sql.Connection con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:system/neha123@localhost:1521:XE");
        java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet rs, rs2;

        String email = request.getParameter("EMAIL");
        String pw = request.getParameter("PW");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from hallMembers where email='"+email+"' and pw='"+pw+"'");
        String s="BothWrong";

        if (rs.next())
        {
            session.putValue("EMAIL", email);
            session.putValue("UNAME", rs.getString("fname"));
            session.putValue("STMT",stmt);
            s = "BothMatch";
        }
        else
        {
            rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("Select EMAIL from hallMembers where EMAIL='"+email+"'");  
            if (rs2.next()) { s = "WrongPw"; }
            else            { s = "WrongEmail"; }
        }
        out.write(s);
    %>
```

I have one entry in the table hallMembers as: email: neha@abc.com and pw: helloneha. If I enter the right info, the showMessage() always shows the response in ans to be WrongEmail. This behavior is very confusing and so I have also tried to use various alert statements to understand the problem but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you "I have one entry in the table hallMembers as: email: neha@abc.com and pw: helloneha. If I enter the right info, the showMessage() seems not to have been called while in any other case the response comes out to be WrongEmail"

It's true because you get just one row when calling sql but in your code you are expecting twice:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select email, pw from hallMembers where email='"+email+"' and pw='"+pw+"'");
String s="BothWrong";
rs.next();//first row
out.print(rs.getString(1));

if (rs.next())//second row
{
```

Try removing the first rs.next which places cursor to first record, where you read the valid record and then again you try to move cursor to next row which is not present and you end up executing else part which says either wrong password or wrong email.

Comment: Thanks almas for the reply but the first time I gave rs.next(), after that I tried to get the response in rs printed by directly running the matchDetails.jsp. But it shows HTTP Status 500- Internal Server Error and a java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not ended properly.

Comment: And after removing the extra rs.next(), as I have also edited in the above code, the problem still remains.

Comment: `out.print(rs.getString(1));
            session.putValue("EMAIL", email);
            session.putValue("UNAME", rs.getString("fname"));
            session.putValue("STMT",stmt);` Does it print email from above? you are saying rs.getString fname which you never selected from you select statement? You are storing entire statement in session any reason?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! And, @almas, as corrected by you so far, I have again made the relevant edit. Now please guide me along this one too. After checking with the entries in database, the ans is finally getting set to "BothMatch". But in the showMessage() function, the control does not seem to pass into into the if-else statements. Why is that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: where are you calling showMessage? Btw this is follow up message and i would suggest you start the chat for this or open a new question..

Comment: I have called the showMessage() function in checkDetails() function.